# Argument cannot be null in Rest Apex class

Tags: apexrest, null-pointer

I am trying to send data from salesforce to external system and have written web service but even after properly encoding every parameter, i am getting argument cannot be null due to which data is not getting sent.
Please help me with the possible cause of error.

below is the code snippet:

```
 @future(Callout=true)    
     public static void makePostCallout2(String first, String last, String em, String conID, String acctID, String utype, String prod, String expDate, String acctOwner, String lmd, String flag, String createdBy, String origin) {

        Http http = new Http();

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
         request.setEndpoint('***********************');
        request.setMethod('PUT');
       request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', '*****************');
         request.setBody('firstname='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(first,'UTF-8')+'&lastname='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(last,'UTF-8')+'&email='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(em,'UTF-8')+'&contactID='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(conID,'UTF-8')+'&accountID='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(acctID,'UTF-8')+'&userType='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(uType,'UTF-8')+'&product='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(prod,'UTF-8')+'&expiryDate='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(expDate,'UTF-8')+'&accountOwner='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(acctOwner,'UTF-8')+'&lastModifiedDate='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(lmd,'UTF-8')+'&operation='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(flag,'UTF-8')+'&createdBy='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(createdBy,'UTF-8')+'&creationOrigin='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(origin,'UTF-8'));        
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
         system.debug('this is after processing response');
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
    }
```

the argument cannot be null is occuring in initializing end point and method in headers.. for privacy reason, endpoint and token has been masked.

Comment: Just to confirm, is the error happening on `request.setBody`? If so, you should implement some sanity checks on your parameters before trying to encode them, or introduce error handling.

Comment: Which specific line throws the exception? Are the masked parameters provided as literal strings or sourced from the database?

Comment: error is happening after request.setBody and masked parameters are provided as literal strings only.

Comment: @DrewKennedy This should have been an answer. EncodingUtil methods don't like null values.

Answer (score 2):

You're receiving this error because you're providing `null` as values for encoding. To better handle these situations, you can either perform sanity checks on your parameters, or introduce some error handling.

An example of sanity checks would be

```
@future(Callout=true)    
public static void makePostCallout2(String first, String last, String em, String conID, String acctID, String utype, String prod, String expDate, String acctOwner, String lmd, String flag, String createdBy, String origin) {

    if (String.isBlank(first)) {
        //do something with "first"
    }

    if (String.isBlank(last)) {
        //do something with "last"
    }
```

This isn't the cleanest approach, but has its place. The more recommended approach would be to introduce some basic error handling:

```
@future(Callout=true)    
public static void makePostCallout2(String first, String last, String em, String conID, String acctID, String utype, String prod, String expDate, String acctOwner, String lmd, String flag, String createdBy, String origin) {
    try {
        Http http = new Http();

        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('***********************');
        request.setMethod('PUT');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', '*****************');
        request.setBody('firstname='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(first,'UTF-8')+'&lastname='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(last,'UTF-8')+'&email='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(em,'UTF-8')+'&contactID='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(conID,'UTF-8')+'&accountID='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(acctID,'UTF-8')+'&userType='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(uType,'UTF-8')+'&product='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(prod,'UTF-8')+'&expiryDate='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(expDate,'UTF-8')+'&accountOwner='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(acctOwner,'UTF-8')+'&lastModifiedDate='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(lmd,'UTF-8')+'&operation='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(flag,'UTF-8')+'&createdBy='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(createdBy,'UTF-8')+'&creationOrigin='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(origin,'UTF-8'));        
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        system.debug('this is after processing response');
        // Parse the JSON response
        if (response.getStatusCode() != 200) {
            System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
        }
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        //do something with iae
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do something with e
    }
}
```

Also, wherever this is being called from, you may also want to check *why* you're feeding in bad data to begin with.

Comment: after applying all the null checks, i am getting 415 Unsupported Media Type error..

Comment: This was happening before also when i was trying to send parameters in body without encoding methods.. dont why its happening. in postman its returning data but in apex its returning unsupported media type error

Comment: That sounds like a completely different issue. To avoid this becoming an XY problem, I'd recommend creating another question for that particular issue. For your benefit though, here's the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) on 415 errors.